# What is the purpose of sx prop in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
<Box style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
  <Post post={post} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
</Box>
```

```
<Box sx={{ padding: "20px" }}>
  <Post post={post} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
</Box>
```

**React.js + Material UI**

The above two examples do the same thing, one uses sx prop in material UI, the other is regular inline styling using css, so what is the point of "sx"? and should it always be used over style={{}} when using Material UI?

Answer (score 24):

> The `sx` prop is a shortcut for defining custom style that has access
> to the theme

It can accept any CSS properties plus a few extra from MUI.

There are differences like :

1. **shortHand:** `padding-top` can be written as `pt`.
2. **access to theme:** If you define your theme in material UI, sx prop can directly access its properties like `color`.
   Example from the doc :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Box, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/system';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      paper: '#fff',
    },
    text: {
      primary: '#173A5E',
      secondary: '#46505A',
    },
    action: {
      active: '#001E3C',
    },
    success: {
      dark: '#009688',
    },
  },
});

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          bgcolor: 'background.paper',
          boxShadow: 1,
          borderRadius: 2,
          p: 2,
          minWidth: 300,
        }}
      >
        <Box sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>Sessions</Box>
        <Box sx={{ color: 'text.primary', fontSize: 34, fontWeight: 'medium' }}>
          98.3 K
        </Box>
        <Box
          sx={{
            color: 'success.dark',
            display: 'inline',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            mx: 0.5,
            fontSize: 14,
          }}
        >
          +18.77%
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ color: 'text.secondary', display: 'inline', fontSize: 14 }}>
          vs. last week
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Properties in sx object can have functions as valuse. These functions have access to `theme` too.

```
<Box sx={{ height: (theme) => theme.spacing(10) }} />
```

3. **Grid properties:** `gap`, `rowGap` and `columnGap` are available in sx.
4. **Responsive styles:** You can define properties according to the different MUI device size shorthands:

```
borderColor : { xs: "red", sm: "green" },
```

5. **Access to child components:** You can change styles of chlid components using nested styles:

```
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{
    '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
      color: 'white',
    },
  }}
/>
```

6. **Much more than CSS:** The `sx` prop also supports CSS syntax including child and pseudo-selectors, media queries etc.
   Eg:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    // some styles
    ":hover": {  //psuedo-selectors
      boxShadow: 6,
    },
    '@media print': {  //media-queries
      width: 300,
    },
  }}
>
```

Sources:

[1.](https://smartdevpreneur.com/material-ui-sx-prop/#:%7E:text=MUI%20v5%20has%20migrated%20to,%7D%20sets%20margin%2Dtop)

[2.](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/)

Comment: The best anwser!

Comment: what is `sx` stand for ? I find it is hard to remember `sx` or `xs` ,

Comment: @vanduc1102 They don't say what it stands for in the official docs, but I guess it is some kind of short-hand for "Style eXtension" / "Styles eXtended"?

Answer (score 3):

The `sx` props allows you to use all the mui system properties along with CSS properites.
with `style={{}}` aproch you add the CSS properties directly but you cannot use the mui properties in it. e.g. theme properties.

with SX props: you can set color in theme once. then use same color in all your app. then in future you want to change color you can change it in theme only once and it will apply to all the app automatically.

```
sx={{ color: 'primary.main' }}
```

with Style: but then you have to remember exact colorcode while coding your app and then in future if you decided to change you have to change everywhere in app.

```
style={{ color: '#00ff00' }}
```

also some CSS properties you can directly add to components.

e.g.

```
<Box height="100px" >... </Box> is same as 
<Box sx={{height: '100px'}}>...</Box>
```

check below pages for more details.

https://mui.com/system/basics/#all-inclusive

https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/